# Principal component analysis for "uneven" data

Tags: pca

Suppose I have data consisting of three layers. Layer $i$ consists of $n_i$ 2D points, $i=1,2,3$. Here $n_1$, $n_2$ and $n_3$ may be different. I would like to somehow apply the Principal Component Analysis (PCA) to project this data to one 2D point. Is there any way of doing that?

My knowledge is that one usually projects multidimensional points to the plane spanned by the most significant principal axes. The background here is that an experiment yields $k$ sets of the above data, and one would like to visually represent each of these data as a single point in the plane in order to compare them by various measures of closeness.

Added: I am willing to consider each layer separately. That is, I just have a set of 2D points. What does it mean to "use PCA to produce one point representing that set of points"?